# Numba TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic exception_match>) found for signature

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, numba

I am facing on `TypingError` while I work with `numba` .

My function works fine without `@jit(nopython=True)`, however with it, it raise `TypingError`.

**ERROR**

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic exception_match>) found for signature:
 
exception_match(none, ValueError)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Intrinsic in function 'exception_match': File: numba\core\unsafe\eh.py: Line 47.
        With argument(s): '(none, ValueError)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         UnsupportedError: Exception matching is limited to <class 'Exception'>
  raised from C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\numba\core\unsafe\eh.py:55

During: resolving callee type: Function(<intrinsic exception_match>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-19-6b44dd15c90f> (6)
```

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
from math import factorial
from numba import jit
import pandas as pd

@jit(nopython=True)
def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
    try:
        window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
        order = np.abs(np.int(order))
    except ValueError :
        raise ValueError("window size & order have to be of type int")
    
    if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
        raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
    
    if window_size < order + 2:
        raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
    
    order_range = range(order+1)
    half_window = (window_size -1) // 2

    b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, 
                                                           half_window+1)])
    m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
    firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
    lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
    y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
    return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')


yaw = np.array(pd.read_csv('D:\datasets\df.csv')['yaw'])
sg_yaw = savitzky_golay(yaw , window_size =3 , order = 1, deriv=0, rate=1)
```

Comment: Does `factorial` work with numba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

```
UnsupportedError: Exception matching is limited to <class 'Exception'>
```

indicates that you must use `Exception`, not one of its derived classes.

Copied from the [docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html?highlight=try#try-except):

The `try .. except` construct is partially supported. The following forms of are supported:

- the bare except that captures all exceptions:

  ```
    try:
        ...
    except:
        ...
  ```
- using exactly the Exception class in the except clause:

  ```
    try:
        ...
    except Exception:
        ...
  ```